# Passing a callback through cl-function

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm trying to use the excellent [request.el](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-request/) library request data from a REST API:

```
(request
 "http://httpbin.org/get"
 :params '(("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2"))
 :parser 'json-read
 :success (function*
           (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
             (message "I sent: %S" (assoc-default 'args data)))))
```

Which works nicely. Being a lisp-newbie I don't really know what the `function*` does here, I just got that from the `request.el`-examples.

I then tried to wrap this call in a function to reduce boilerplate like so:

```
(defun my/do-request (callback)
  (request
   "http://httpbin.org/get"
   :params '(("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2"))
   :parser 'json-read
   :success callback))

(my/do-request (lambda (data)
                 (message "got data: %s" data)))
```

But the callback is not being called? I also tried passing the callback like this:

```
(defun my/do-request (callback)
  (request
   "http://httpbin.org/get"
   :params '(("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2"))
   :parser 'json-read
   :success (function*
             (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
               (callback data)))))
```

with the same result. I thought I might need lexical binding here, but that also didn't help.

How can I reduce the boilerplate code here?

Comment: @coredump How is your callback defined? I've edited my question to contain my the call to `my/do-request` with a lambda (which is not working for me).

I'm on emacs 26.1 btw, but this shouldn't make a difference, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When calling the new function, it is generally a good practice to try it with the exact same value you originally had:

```
(my/do-request
 (function*
  (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
   (message "I sent: %S" (assoc-default 'args data)))))
```

The above prints the desired message.

#### First approach

You called the code as follows, and nothing was printed:

```
(my/do-request (lambda (data)
                 (message "got data: %s" data)))
```

It turns out there is an error, but unfortunately it does not reach the user. In case of doubt, you should enable the debugger:

```
(setf debug-on-error t)
```

You can eval the above in the `*scratch*` buffer or in the minibuffer after doing <kbd>**M-:**</kbd> (`eval-expression`).

Then, when you reevaluate the call, the following should be displayed:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) 8)
  (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data))(:data ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . .....) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) :symbol-status success :error-thrown nil :response [cl-struct-request-response 200 nil ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . .....) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) nil success "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" nil (:params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response #0) #<killed buffer> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: keep-alive\nServer: gunicorn/19.8.1\nDate: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:44:15 GMT\nContent-Type: application/json\nContent-Length: 249\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\nVia: 1.1 vegur\n" nil curl nil])
  apply((lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) (:data ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) :symbol-status success :error-thrown nil :response [cl-struct-request-response 200 nil ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) nil success "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" nil (:params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response #1) #<killed buffer> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: keep-alive\nServer: gunicorn/19.8.1\nDate: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:44:15 GMT\nContent-Type: application/json\nContent-Length: 249\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\nVia: 1.1 vegur\n" nil curl nil]))
  apply(apply (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) (:data ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) :symbol-status success :error-thrown nil :response [cl-struct-request-response 200 nil ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) nil success "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" nil (:params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response #1) #<killed buffer> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: keep-alive\nServer: gunicorn/19.8.1\nDate: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:44:15 GMT\nContent-Type: application/json\nContent-Length: 249\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\nVia: 1.1 vegur\n" nil curl nil]))
  request--safe-apply((lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) (:data ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) :symbol-status success :error-thrown nil :response [cl-struct-request-response 200 nil ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) nil success "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" nil (:params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response #1) #<killed buffer> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: keep-alive\nServer: gunicorn/19.8.1\nDate: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:44:15 GMT\nContent-Type: application/json\nContent-Length: 249\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\nVia: 1.1 vegur\n" nil curl nil]))
  request--callback(#<killed buffer> :params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response [cl-struct-request-response 200 nil ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) nil success "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" nil (:params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response #0) #<killed buffer> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: keep-alive\nServer: gunicorn/19.8.1\nDate: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:44:15 GMT\nContent-Type: application/json\nContent-Length: 249\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\nVia: 1.1 vegur\n" nil curl nil])
  apply(request--callback #<killed buffer> (:params (("key" . "value") ("key2" . "value2")) :parser json-read :success (lambda (data) (message "got data: %s" data)) :error #[128 "\302\300\303\301\"\"\207" [request-default-error-callback ("http://httpbin.org/get") apply append] 6 "\n\n(fn &rest ARGS2)"] :url "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" :response [cl-struct-request-response 200 nil ((args (key . "value") (key2 . "value2")) (headers (Accept . "*/*") (Accept-Encoding . "deflate, gzip") (Connection . "close") (Host . "httpbin.org") (User-Agent . "curl/7.55.1")) (origin . ...) (url . "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2")) nil success "http://httpbin.org/get?key=value&key2=value2" nil #0 #<killed buffer> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nConnection: keep-alive\nServer: gunicorn/19.8.1\nDate: Thu, 05 Jul 2018 11:44:15 GMT\nContent-Type: application/json\nContent-Length: 249\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Credentials: true\nVia: 1.1 vegur\n" nil curl nil]))
  request--curl-callback(#<process request curl> "finished\n")
```

Based on the documentation, the callback function should be variadic, which means the following works:

```
(lambda (&rest args) (message "got data: %s" args))
```

But then, you will see too much data.

Arguments are passed as key/values pairs. In order to get the data associated with the `:data` symbol, you would have to do:

```
(lambda (&rest args)
  (message "got data: %s" (getf args :data)))
```

The resulting value is an association list, from which you can access the `'args` entry like done above (i.e. `(assoc-default 'args data)`).

But, instead of doing `(getf args :data)`, you can also write:

```
(lambda (&key data) ...)
```

The special `&key` symbol is used to automatically access the value associated with `:data` in the implicit list of arguments. **But**, keyword parameters are from Common Lisp, Emacs Lisp does not know how to handle `&key` out of the box. That's why there is a `(function* ...)` macro that wraps around the lambda. You then have the choice of using the `function*` macro or deal with the argument list by yourself, as shown above. It depends on what you need. As suggested by the documentation, if you use `&key`, you should also use `&allow-other-keys`.

#### Second approach

In your second approach, having `debug-on-entry` set to `t` indicates that `callback` is not a known function:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function callback)
```

This is due to Emacs Lisp being a Lisp-2, i.e. you cannot call a function given in argument simply by putting it as the first element of a function call. Emacs Lisp understands the syntax as *"call the function named callback"*, not *"call the function object bound to variable callback"*. You'd need to use `funcall`:

```
(function*
  (lambda (&key data &allow-other-keys)
    (funcall callback data)))
```

But with the above, now the error is that `callback` is an undefined variable. And now, this is due to dynamic scoping. If you evalute the following line and reevaluate the defun, the code works as expected:

```
(setf lexical-binding t)
```

Alternatively, you can put the following as the first line of you file:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t -*-
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I understand the usage of `&key` now. Still don't get why my second approach was not working though? Ideally, I'd like `my/do-request` to pull out the `data` so that I can pass a simple `(lambda (data) (...))` callback to `my/do-request`.